# Add constant integer to visually selected numbers

Tags: regular-expression, visual-block

I have a file like the following : two different files were yanked one after another, and the numbers subsequently don't match anymore.

```
                ...   46
atom   142   option   47
atom   143   option   48       
atom    12   option    7  # There's a discontinuity in the numbers at this line
atom    13   option    8
atom    14   option    9
atom    ...
```

I would like to take the columns of numbers **using visual-selection**, and **add the missing constant** (in my example, for the first column, adding 132 to the last three lines would be perfect).

I don't know if regexp allow mathematical operations (otherwise I could try  a macro using Ctrl-X / Ctrl-A, but it won't use visual selection anymore and I'd like to keep it).

(The expected result would be something like:)

```
                ...   46
atom   142   option   47
atom   143   option   48       
atom   144   option    7  # Discontinuity in the first numbers column is gone !
atom   145   option    8
atom   146   option    9
atom    ...
```

Comment: As of Vim 7.4.754+ you can use `<c-a>`/`<c-x>` in visual mode. See `:h v_CTRL-A`

Comment: According to `vim --version` I only have Vim 7.2, and I cant update that (I do not have admin rights).

Comment: The easy way: install the [VisIncr](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/#VISINCR) plugin, select the column from the last good number down, and run `:II`.  The harder way: if the first bad number is on line 73, do something like this: `:73,$s/\d\+/\=submatch(0)+132/`, then fix the align.

Comment: _I only have Vim 7.2, and I cant update that_ - The last release of Vim 7.2 was 7.2.433, in 2010.  Motion to fire your sysadmin. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Visually select all the lines you want to increment, and do the following:

```
:s/\d\+/\=submatch(0) + 132
```

Does exactly what you describe. Visually selects a bunch of numbers, and adds a mathematical constant to each of them. If you leave of the `/g` flag, it will only increment the first number on each line. This uses the "expression register". To learn more, `:help "=` has much more useful info.

Since you mentioned trying a macro, here's what you were probably missing from your macro. Add `gv` to the beginning of your macro. This reselects your last visual selection. For example:

```
qqgv<C-a>q132@q
```

(Note, I don't know if this works in 7.2, and since I don't have it installed I can't test it)

Answer (score 9):

As of Vim 7.4.754+ you can use `<c-a>`/`<c-x>` in visual mode. See `:h v_CTRL-A`.

However since you can not upgrade Vim you may want to look into [speeddating.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-speeddating) which does some visual incrementing.

There are [other plugins](http://vimawesome.com/?q=visual%20increment) that might work as well:

- [visualinc](https://github.com/deris/vim-visualinc)
- [visual-increment.vim](https://github.com/triglav/vim-visual-increment)

Otherwise you need to use a macro or use visual mode and then use `:normal`.

```
:norm 132<c-v><c-a>
```

For more help see:

```
:h :norm
:h v_CTRL-A
```

Comment: Beware that `<c-a>`/`<c-x>` in visual mode took a while to actually become usable.  They used to segfault and behaved in unexpected ways in their early days.  Just FYI.

Comment: @SatoKatsura, would you recommend version 7.4.1634+ instead? I am reading the [patches from here](http://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/patches/7.4/README).

Comment: I haven't paid much attention to this particular point, but there were several patches posted by several people affecting it.  7.4.1634 was indeed relevant, but I don't know if it was the last one.  Vim 8+ should be a safer test soon. :)

Answer (score 4):

**edit :** answer posted before knowing OP had no support for the visual increment.

---

Here is a possible solution:

1. Select the last *good* number, `143` and yank it.
2. In visual-block (<kbd>C-V</kbd>), select the column under the `143` you just yanked (where you want to update the numbers).
3. <kbd>p</kbd> will past `143` over the entire selection.
4. Select again the pasted `143` column.
5. <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>C-A</kbd> will increment gradually the selection, giving you overall increment.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is to yank the number before and after the sequential break and let vim do the math for you.

```
vnoremap <C-a> :call CalculatedIncrement(@p, @o)<CR>

function! CalculatedIncrement(first, second)
   if (a:first > a:second)
      exe 'normal! '. (a:first-a:second+1) .'^A'
   else
      exe 'normal! '. (a:second-a:first+1) .'^X'
   endif
endfunction
```

Note that you can't just copy and paste this. You'll need to re-input `^A` and `^X` yourself with `<C-v>+<C-A>`, etc.

To use this, yank the first number into buffer p: `"pyiw`, and the second number into o: `"oyiw`. Then just visually select the lines you want to change and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>.